# See currently assigned variables in Mathematica

Tags: mathematica

I've noticed that in a notebook, if I define a variable, and then delete the definition, the variable stays assigned.  Is there a quick way to see all the variables that are assigned?  I can find them by using the debugger, but it is kind of tedious for a quick check.

Comment: `?Global\`*` works.

Answer (score 1):

*Mathematica* associates with each symbol a set of [values](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ManipulatingValueLists.html). [OwnValues](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OwnValues.html) is the one that stores value assignments to the symbol.

This code returns the list of symbol names (as strings) for those symbols whose `OwnValues` is non-empty, i.e. the symbol has been assigned a value:

```
Select[Names["Global`*"], 
 ToExpression[#, InputForm, OwnValues] =!= {} &]
```